# How to use defined variables in Nftables though terminal (not in script)

Tags: firewall, nftables

I want to run these two commands in a interactive shell, one after the other (as root and with the "filter" table and the "input" chain loaded):

```
nft define lala=1.2.3.4
nft add rule ip filter input ip saddr \$lala accept
```

You can see I escape the "$" to avoid shell expansion. But I get this error message "Unkown identifier 'lala'". If I don't escape the "$", I get this error message instead: "Syntax error, unexepected accept". If I write *\$$lala* instead, I get this error message instead: "Syntax error, uneepcted accept, expecting string" and this wrong rule is shown: add rule ip filter input ip saddr $ accept.

So, what's the correct syntax to be able to use Nft variables inside a interactive shell. Doing the same inside a Nft script works well (without worrying about escaping).

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Symbolic variables](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#SYMBOLIC_VARIABLES) in use by the `nft` *userspace* command are resolved into their values *only* by this command. The `nft` command resolves the variable into its assigned value to assemble the final result. *Then* the `nft` commands uses the [netlink API](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/netlink.7) to communicate with the kernel and send it a new rule to add. The kernel *never* sees `lala=1.2.3.4` nor has any concept of symbolic variable.

So if you split your `nft` command in two invocations what happens is:

- The first `nft` command defines a symbolic variable for its own later use. But does nothing else. It doesn't even have to communicate with the kernel since no ruleset change is asked. (Actually it does communicate, but to send "nothing", like with the command `nft ''`). At the end of the command the definition of the symbol is lost, without having been used.
- A second invocation of the `nft` command needs to resolve the `$lala` symbol, but cannot find a definition: `nft` stops with an error.

So this must be all done in *one* `nft` invocation so the second statement still knows about the symbolic variable. There are multiple ways to do this. I left in examples below shell and `nft`'s prompts which shouldn't be typed.

- interactive [`nft`](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#OPTIONS)

  > `-i, --interactive`
  >    Read input from an interactive readline CLI. You can use `quit` to exit, or use the EOF marker, normally this is CTRL-D.

  ```
  # nft -i
  nft> define lala=1.2.3.4
  nft> add rule ip filter input ip saddr $lala accept
  nft> quit
  ```
- two commands in a single `nft` invocation.

  ```
  # nft 'define lala=1.2.3.4; add rule ip filter input ip saddr $lala accept'
  ```

  Note the additional `;` needed because in this context `nft` receives one line of parameters, but they should be split into two logical commands. Also `nft` having its own parser, it doesn't care if commands are received as a single command parameter or multiple separate parameters. Here everything was enclosed in a pair of `''` to avoid shell issues with both `;` and `$` characters.
- Then `nft` has an option to read from a file. When reading from a file, all the input is part of the same `nft` command context.

  > `-f, --file filename`
  >   Read input from filename. If filename is -, read from stdin.
  >
  > nft scripts must start `#!/usr/sbin/nft -f`

  So with a file named `test.nft` having this content:

  ```
  define lala=1.2.3.4
  add rule ip filter input ip saddr $lala accept
  ```

  This can then be used:

  ```
  # nft -f test.nft
  ```

  The variant below executes a script in the "*nftables* language". Having a `test.nft` file content as:

  ```
  #!/usr/sbin/nft -f
  define lala=1.2.3.4
  add rule ip filter input ip saddr $lala accept
  ```

  Then:

  ```
  # chmod a+rx test.nft
  # ./test.nft
  ```

  This would also have worked:

  ```
  # nft -f - <<'EOF'
  > define lala=1.2.3.4
  > add rule ip filter input ip saddr $lala accept
  > EOF
  ```

For each previous command, the resulting ruleset is the same (assuming table and chain were created before):

```
# nft list chain ip filter input
table ip filter {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
        ip saddr 1.2.3.4 accept
    }
}
```

There won't be anymore any trace of `$lala` left: the kernel never received `$lala` but only `1.2.3.4` and that's what it gives back.

Comment: Oh, what a wonderful answer!! Thanks a lot!!!